# Near neutral rod to cap of electroscope

Tags: electrostatics

If we have a charged electroscope and bring a neutral rod close to the electroscope, do the leaves of electroscope come closer together or move further apart or stay the same?

Answer (score 0):

If the neutral rod is an insulator, its proximity has no effect on the leaves.

If the neutral rod is a conductor, the rod will become polarized, and the separation of the leaves will be reduced.

Comment: Please explain in detail.

Comment: Suppose the electroscope is charged positively. This positive charge will polarize the conducting rod. The polarized rod will pull positive charge from the leaves of the electroscope towards the cap of the electroscope. As the positive charge on the leaves is reduced, they come together.

Comment: Ok. but when positive charge of leaves decreases, positive charge in top of the electroscope increases. therefore rod becomes polarized more and again this process continues. when stop this process ?

Comment: my mean is that if top of electroscope becomes more positive. rod becomes more polarized. then top of the electroscope become more positive and...... when stop this process ?

Comment: The process stops when the energy of the system is minimal. The system consists of two capacitors in series: the capacitance between rod en cap, and the capacitance between leaves and the case. Initally a positive charge Q is on the cap, and then the system is allowed to redistribute the charges and reach its equilibrium state. The energy to be minimized is Σ ½CV²